# RStudio ggplot name points with different column than x or y

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I have following dataset:

```
CATEGORY ID   Mode_A   Mode_B   Mean_A   Mean_A
A         1      4       2       2.1      3.4
A         2      1       2       4.2      2.7 
B         3      1       1       3.2      4.1 
B         4      4       2       1.5      1.2
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Kp1.png)

I have created following plot:

```
ggplot(data = tabla_moda) + 
 geom_point(mapping = aes(x = Media_Impacto, y = Media_Esfuerzo, color = Moda_Impacto, size = Moda_Esfuerzo)
)
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nupr8.png)

I am trying to add to all the points in the graph ID rowname from my DATASET

I have tried:

```
ggplot(data = tabla_moda) + 
 geom_point(mapping = aes(x = Media_Impacto, y = Media_Esfuerzo, color = Moda_Impacto, size = Moda_Esfuerzo) +
               ggrepel::geom_text_repel(label = ID, nudge_x=0.45, nudge_y=0.1,check_overlap=T)
)

ggplot(data = tabla_moda, mapping = aes(x = Media_Impacto, y = Media_Esfuerzo, color = Moda_Impacto, size = Moda_Esfuerzo, label = rownames(ID))) + 
 geom_point()  +
  geom_text(label = ID, nudge_x=0.45, nudge_y=0.1,check_overlap=T)
```

But I am always getting ID, same error:

> ID object not found

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I don't think you should have `rownames()`, maybe just `label = ID`?

Comment: I have tried, but it was giving the above error. The issue was I didn't include it as an aesthetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the ID is a variable of your dataset, so you should include it always as an aesthetic, I think this should work:

```
ggplot(data = tabla_moda, mapping = aes(x = Media_Impacto, y = Media_Esfuerzo, color = Moda_Impacto, size = Moda_Esfuerzo)) + 
geom_point()  +
geom_text(aes(label = ID), nudge_x=0.45, nudge_y=0.1,check_overlap=T)
```